# TF2 / Keras slice tensor using [:, :, 0]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

In TF 2.0 Beta I'm trying:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(240, 2), dtype=tf.float32)
print(x.shape) # (None, 240, 2)
a = x[:, :, 0]
print(a.shape) # <unknown>
```

In TF 1.x I could do:

```
x = tf1.placeholder(tf1.float32, (None, 240, 2)
a = x[:, :, 0]
```

and it would work fine. How do I achieve this in TF 2.0? I think

```
tf.split(x, 2, axis=2)
```

may work, however I'd like to use slicing rather than hard coding the 2 (dim of axis 2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that the object returned from `Input` represents a layer rather than anything analogous with a placeholder or tensor. So the `x` in your tf 2.0 code above is a layer object whereas the `x` in your tf 1.x code is a placeholder for a tensor.

You can define a slicing layer to perform the operation. There are out of the box layers available but, for a simple slice like this, a `Lambda` layer is super easy to read and perhaps comes closest to the way you have been used to slicing in tf 1.x.

Something like this:

```
input_lyr = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(240, 2), dtype=tf.float32)
sliced_lyr = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,0])
```

which you can use in your keras model like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    input_lyr,
    sliced_lyr,
    # ...
    # <other layers>
    # ...
])
```

Of course the above is specific to a *keras* model. If, instead, you have a tensor rather than a keras layer object then the slicing works exactly as before. Something like this:

```
my_tensor = tf.random.uniform((8,240,2))
sliced = my_tensor[:,:,0]

print(my_tensor.shape)
print(sliced.shape)
```

outputs:

```
(8, 240, 2)
(8, 240)
```

as expected